# Mysql IF two columns equal and if they are both greater than one

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, where-clause

I have a query that pulls users in a list. It pulls a list of people that you can "fight", You shouldn't be able to fight yourself, or fight someone in your "clan".

```
 $select = mysql_query("SELECT id,username,clan FROM `users` WHERE username != '".$user['username']."' AND IF clan>0 THEN clan != ".$user['clan']."");
```

This query "tries" to see if the selected row's clan > 0 "Means they are in a clan", then it should see if they are in the same clan as the user. IF so, skip that row. Also, it is worth nothing that if you aren't in a clan, you should be able to fight others also not in a clan (0).

- Can't fight yourself
- Or anyone in your clan

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id,username,clan 
FROM `users` 
WHERE username != '".$user['username']."' 
AND (clan = 0 OR clan != ".$user['clan'].")"
```

Comment: Not positive I have the php string concatenation syntax correct, but the query part should be what you want.

Comment: Terrific! I can't believe I didn't come up with that :P

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,username,clan 
FROM `users` 
WHERE username != '".$user['username']."' 
  AND (
    (clan != ".$user['clan'].") OR
    (clan = 0 AND ".$user['clan']." = 0)
  )
```

If clanny can't fight clanless, just add check for clan=0 in first part of OR and so on.